# Emailing an Invoice for small freelancing work

Tags: invoices

I recently started doing some small freelance work (USA). I need to email an invoice. It is just for one job. How should I do that?
I do not have a company or anything like that.

Comment: Use an invoice template. There are probably a bazillion of them available free on the internet.

Comment: Although in most countries it's not necessary to set up a company to be a freelancer, it often is a good idea. Sooner or later, you will need to understand how to file your taxes correctly.

Comment: Also, the bigger the project, the more important it is to have a written agreement before even starting work and sending an invoice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just send them an email, with an invoice PDF attached. Some clients need an invoice to be in PDF format for accounting purposes. If you want, repeat the same information within the email body itself.

Your invoice should contain:

- Who you are (your name, your contact details, your company details)
- Who the client is (their name, their contact details, their company)
- A list of services provided, with their cost, in a table. Also list any expenses that you expect the client to pay for.
- The date of the invoice
- The due date, that is, the date by which the client should pay the invoice
- All the details on how to make the payment. Make it easy for your clients to pay you and don't skip any details
- You may find it useful for accounting purposes to include an invoice number

That is the basics. You can find plenty of invoice templates that look professional by searching online.